# What area of mathematics would this kind of question fall under?

Tags: education

**To be clear, I do not need a solution**. I also do not have the wording correct as this is from a Japanese math workbook.

What area of Mathematics would you place this under? (I want to find workbooks in English with similar questions):

"There are 3 departments at a university: x, y and z.

Department z accounts for 23% of the total number of students in all departments.

Department y is 5/6 the size of department x.

What percentage of the total number of students does x make up?"

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe percentages? Or algebra? Equations?

Comment: Algebra precalculus.

Comment: algebra precalculus word problems

Comment: Thank you everyone!